# examples of custom google maps

Tags: google-maps

I'm looking for examples of how to create my own page/site with google maps API. 
Specifically, if anyone knows of example for road trip. Let me explain:
1. Let's say I'd like to drive from california to maine, obviously I'm not going to get there in a day. 
2. Now let's say I'd like to leave at 5p.m drive all the way into the night, 11p.m - 12.am for example, so it would be nice to see where I can be after 5, 6 hours of driving. 
3. Standard google (yahoo, bing, etc.) don't have that option (unless I don't know how to enable it), but they only give you total time, for example 30 hours. I can't nor I don't want to drive for 30 hours straight. I'd like to see where I can be after x hours.

anyway, this is getting to long, so if anyone has a collection of good/nice/cool examples with sample code, please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the time you want to leave, the time of arrival as given by your api you can calculate the average speed.

Using the average speed, you can know how many kilometers you can drive in a given time. If you know how many kilometers, you know where you are.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if you are using the API it returns information about each step (distance, time, etc.).  You can then use that information to show the user where they will be based on what time they started.  [API Information here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#JSON).